# How do you fill an html form field from a typescript array or map?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an html form with an input element. I have an array of typescript values.  I want to populate the value of the input field with a value from the array, depending on the name of the input field.

I have an html table input input field, like this:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="totalFat" value={{totalFat}}>
</td>
```

In the typescript I have

```
totalFat = '2.5g';
```

This correctly displays 2.5g in the input field.

But how to get the totalFat variable from an array, instead of hard-coding it?

EDIT:
I have an array nutrientGuis: NutrientGui[]. NutrientGui is an object `{name:string,amount:number}`.

Creating the nutrientGuis array is failing with "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Vitamin A, IU')"

That is the first record in the source.  Here is that record:

```
amount: 3360
id: 1104
name: "Vitamin A, IU"
source: "Lab"
units: "IU"
```

And the for loop that tries to add it to the nutrient array is:

```
for (let nutrientGui of this.myFoodGui.nutrientGuis) {
  console.log("nutrientGui=", nutrientGui);
  this.nutrientGuis[nutrientGui.name] = nutrientGui.amount;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Submitting a question on stackoverflow used to be logical.  Now it breaks it up into steps and doesn't show you what it will look like before you submit.  You have to hope and pray it looks like you intended.  This post is a good example.  Notice how the code format is messed up?  How to get back to doing it the old way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do that using a key-value array. Something like:

```
interface Foo {
   [key: string]: number;
}


let foo:Foo[] = [];
foo.push({
  'totalFat': 1337
});
```

Then, from your template:

```
<td> <input type="text" name="totalFat" value={{foo[name]}}> </td>
```

Didn’t had a chance to run it, but give it a try.

Comment: I updated my post where I applied something something like your suggestion, but now a new error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="Total Fat" value="{{nutrients['Total Fat']}}">
```

we use double quotes to enclose the entire attribute value, and single quotes to enclose the object key inside the attribute value.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It at least builds now.  I always thought double quotes and single quotes were interchangeable.  But creating the array is not working.  I'll update the post with "EDIT2" to explain.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I finally came up with.

**.ts**

```
nutrients = {};
  getNutrients() {
    for (let nutrient of this.food.nutrient) {
      this.nutrients[nutrient.name] = nutrient.amount + nutrient.units;
    }
  }
```

.html

```
<td class="dv">
   <input type="text" name="Total lipid (fat)"
          value="{{nutrients['Total lipid (fat)']}}">
</td>
```